# How to git diff with relative paths outside of repository?

Tags: git, diff

I like the format of `git diff` and the diffstat, but sometimes I would like to use it outside of any git repository, on two arbitrary directories.  Doing this introduces some undesired extra directory prefixes into the output, though, which I am having trouble getting rid of.

1. Put some initial files into directory `old` (not in any repo).
2. Copy to directory `new` and make some changes.
3. `git diff -p --stat old/ new/`

This *almost* works, but unfortunately the diffstat includes `{old => new}/` as a path prefix and the diff headers show `a/old/...` and `b/new/...`, for example:

```
 {old => new}/src/config.h |  2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

diff --git a/old/src/config.h b/new/src/config.h
index 8158fcc..7ec16df 100644
--- a/old/src/config.h
+++ b/new/src/config.h
@@ -66,7 +66,7 @@
...
```

I want the diff to be entirely relative to the directories specified on the command line, thus not naming them in the resulting output at all (i.e. `{old => new}/` should not appear and the diff headers should only be `a/...` and `b/...`).  I do want it to include the relative path within each directory (e.g. `src/`).  i.e. the "correct" output would be:

```
 src/config.h |  2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

diff --git a/src/config.h b/src/config.h
index 8158fcc..7ec16df 100644
--- a/src/config.h
+++ b/src/config.h
@@ -66,7 +66,7 @@
...
```

I would also like this to work even if `old` and `new` are not sibling directories -- e.g. I might be comparing `old/` and `../foo/bar/new/`, and the output should be exactly identical to the above if they have the same contents.

If, instead of `old` and `new`, I name the directories `a` and `b` (and ensure they're siblings), then I can get the patch part to appear correctly by adding `--no-prefix`, but this still outputs the wrong diffstat.  (This also works if I instead run `diff -ur a/ b/`, but then there's no diffstat, and it doesn't work with different directory names.)

Is there any trick I'm missing to accomplish this?  Note that I'm on a Windows system, so I only have the limited set of posix tools that come with Git for Windows.

Comment: For any 2 files not tracked by the repository,  try `git diff --no-index path1 path2`.

Comment: You can use `diff` and `diffstat`. There's any number of ways to get them on Windows including [Windows Subsystem For Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

Comment: As already noted, `diff` itself does not behave as desired unless the directories are named precisely.  And `diffstat` is not installed by Git for Windows.  Adding `--no-index` does nothing different.

Comment: is there an ulterior use (for example: producing an adequate patch file to be applied) ? if yes, I would simply advise to `sed` your way out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `old` and `new` in another folder and `git init` in that parent folder.

Comment: This does not produce any different output to the original question.  It's certainly not the desired output.